# Except from Hyperion do you know any other hyper-spectral satellites?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, satellite, usgs

There aren't many images for my research area. 
So I am looking for other hyperspectral satellites.
Or maybe another site except USGS?
The area is near here "40.223124, 23.031155"

Comment: Would airborne hyperspectral imagery suffice? Maybe a better question would be: "how can I find out what hyperspectral imagery is available in a study area?"  I checked with weogeo.com (now part of Trimble) and didn't find anything - maybe I didn't search correctly.  Also, maybe there are other catalogs.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall It probably depends on the size of the area the airborne tool can cover. But I don't have any experiences on airborne imagery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only satellite with hyper-spectral imaging capabilities that I've been able to find is [EO-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Observing-1), which has the Hyperion spectrometer you're referencing. 
There could potentially be satellites that aren't in the public eye with such capabilities, perhaps military satellites, but I certainly haven't heard of any.

Perhaps multi-spectral imaging would work for your purposes?

Comment: I definitely need hyper-spectral because I'm dealing with marine and coastal waters, searching for chlorophyll, COD and other similar parameters but also need high resolution.